# Is it Legal to Use Short Circuit Operators Outside a Conditional?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, logical-operators, control-flow, short-circuiting

The following is a questionable [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **This is not a question about how to improve this code.** What I do want to know is whether the standard condones the use of short circuit operators outside a conditional, as is demonstrated in `main`.

```
enum weekday {
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    WEEKDAY_SIZE
};

bool getWeekday(int index, weekday& result) {
    result = static_cast<weekday>(index);

    return index >= 0 && index < static_cast<int>(WEEKDAY_SIZE);
}

bool getName(weekday& index, string& result) {
    switch (static_cast<weekday>(index)) {
    case SUNDAY:
        result = "Sunday";
        break;
    case MONDAY:
        result = "Monday";
        break;
    case TUESDAY:
        result = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case WEDNESDAY:
        result = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case THURSDAY:
        result = "Thursday";
        break;
    case FRIDAY:
        result = "Friday";
        break;
    case SATURDAY:
        result = "Saturday";
        break;
    default:
        assert("Short Circut Failed");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    const int index = 0;
    weekday Weekday;
    string Name;

    getWeekday(index, Weekday) && getName(Weekday, Name);

    cout << Name << endl;
}
```

This works for both Visual Studio 2015 and [gcc 5.1](http://ideone.com/Ra1ke7) without asserting.

Comment: Any particular reason you thought this might be prohibited?

Comment: Yes, of course. Though technically this *is* a conditional expression. But legal ≠ good. Write the logic out: `if (foo()) bar();`. What you’ve written isn’t idiomatic C++.

Comment: @user2357112 Sure, if the second clause does not return a value it's illegal. So returning a value seems to be required by the short circuit operator. What would happen if there was nothing for it to return to?

Comment: @KonradRudolph "What you've writen isn't idiomatic C++" Can you explain what you mean here by "idiomatic C++"?

Comment: @JonathanMee: The value gets ignored. It's the same as if you call, say, `printf` without doing anything with the `int` it returns. (Didn't know `printf` had a return value? Now you know.)

Comment: @JonathanMee “written such that it doesn’t confuse people”. An idiom is a specific way of speaking/writing that’s composed of more than its parts. In programming, it specifically refers to a typical way of programming in a given language that will yield in code that is not only understandable by experts, but that clearly and concisely expresses the intent without danger of (a) confusion and (b) hard to diagnose bugs. Your particular piece of code has a different way of being expressed in C++ that is unarguably more idiomatic. As a consequence, a reader is left wondering why you deviated.

Comment: @user2357112 LOL Actually I did. But since I don't generally do error checking on a `printf`, I tend to use it a lot more with regard to a `scanf` or `sprintf`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I disagree. A verbose function that returns the literal `true` if a certain condition is met is not particularly idiomatic. But like natural language idioms, the clarity in either expression is subjective.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don’t understand that comment. There’s nothing wrong about functions returning a `bool`. But I object to the characterisation of idioms as “subjective” because that implies that we cannot use evidence to quantify them. However, we clearly can. It may be hard, but it’s possible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, but they *are* subjective. As far as natural language idioms go. They don't carry over in translation, or even make sense out-side of a small geographical area. But back to C++. I meant that a function  checking a condition that is written like this: `if(cond) return true; else return false;` is in fact the one that is un-idiomatic.

Comment: @StoryTeller How's that? Ternaries are un-idiomatic? Yuk yuk yuk

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm gonna agree with StoryTeller on this, there are good paradigms that can be used, but taking the question at hand. How would you say that `getWeekday(index, Weekday) && getName(Weekday, Name);` is wrong and `if(getWeekday(index, Weekday) getName(Weekday, Name);` is right? You could make the claim that one is more readable, but that *is* subjective. The fact there are a cacophony of coding standards is proof that idioms are like memes. Even their definition is circle dependent.

Comment: @StoryTeller You’re arguing against a straw man. Nobody (least of all me) said that you should ever write `if (cond) return true; else return false;` — that’s obviously nonsense. But according to your logic it’s subjective and there’s nothing wrong with writing it, which is laughable: a lot is wrong with it.

Comment: @JonathanMee I say it’s wrong because of the explanation I’ve given earlier: it will trip people up because it deviates needlessly from a clear, well-established pattern. There’s simply no reason to write `a() && b();` instead of `if (a()) b();`, and the mere fact that you deviate from such an obvious form will leave people scratching their heads why the hell you chose to write this code, and whether it has some hidden semantic that’s not immediately apparent. Don’t write code as a mind puzzle, write code to convey meaning as clearly as possible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I highly agree with the use of the `if`-statement based on my past experience. What I'm taking issue with the statement that you can "use evidence to quantify" this. It compiles to the same code, yet we use past coding experience reading and writing code to tell us that the `if`-statement is conventional. And as soon as I said "past coding experience" it became a subjective, not objective argument, one that can only be "quantified" with anecdotal evidence, ripe for conflicting anecdotal evidence from opposing points of view. Idioms are nice but they *are* subjective.

Comment: @JonathanMee Sorry to dig this up again but “CommitStrip” just published a cartoon that perfectly illustrates the importance of writing idiomatic, **unsurprising** code: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/01/26/genius-or-stupid/? — This is a cartoon so it may seem like hyperbole, but let me assure you that it is not: this literally happens *all the time*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What's that? You said code reviews? Coding standards? Yes, I hardily agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the C++14 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), section 5.14:

> 1 The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause  4 ). The result is true if
>   both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike & , **&& guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the
>   first operand is false**.
>
> 2 The result is a bool . If the second
>   expression is evaluated, every value computation and side effect
>   associated with the first expression is sequenced before every value
>   computation and side effect associated with the second expression.

The standard says nothing regarding the context of where `&&` is used.  If the left hand side evaluates to false, the right hand side is not evaluated.

In this context, the result of the expression is thrown away, similarly to if you did this:

```
1;
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not the job of the standard to condone coding styles.

There's nothing wrong with your writing `getWeekday(index, Weekday) && getName(Weekday, Name);`

A reader of your code will know that `getName(Weekday, Name)` will not be called if `getWeekday(index, Weekday)` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thanks, "condone" was probably the wrong word. I just wanted to know if it was allowed.

Comment: "A reader of your code will know that " - in my experience that is a presumption the most programmers are in the top 10 percentile.

Comment: @mattnz That depresses me somewhat; perhaps you’re correct. Fortunately for me I’m able to hire in the top 1%.